# Computer Algebra Systems (proposed Stack Exchange area)

Tags: discussion, area51, proposal

Proposed on December 24: a Stack Exchange area on [Computer Algebra Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/81419/computer-algebra-systems?referrer=i3XTuIUbDy2EyzOIw94kGg2).

Do you think such a place would be useful to us here?  As a place to send slightly off-topic questioners?

Comment: This seems mainly covered by [scicomp.SE].

Comment: This would have to include maple and the others as Mathematica already has a community. I think it is small enough of a topic to still be in MSE.

Comment: @quid [scicomp.se] is heavily numerical; Computer Algebra is not their thing. They have the total of 6 Maple questions and 3 Sage questions.

Comment: @Behaviour It is still on-topic there; I once specifically asked a moderator.

Comment: If it's a *programming* question, the question can be asked on SO.  If it's a *math* question, the question can be asked here.  I don't really see the gap that this proposal is filling...

Comment: @anorton Sometimes it's both. And sometimes we don't know until there is an answer. Also, you know that overlap between SE sites is not uncommon. ([emacs.se] being a recent example in-between [so] and [su]).

Comment: @anorton Questions having to do with the design and use of computer algebra systems are best placed on a site that will attract users with such esoteric expertise. Many would not follow a more general site such as MSE/MO or a general site for computational science because only a very small percentage of the questions would pertain to Computer Algebra.

Comment: Ok, I now see the purpose of the proposed site.

Comment: Cf. also http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70511/sage

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the proposal has failed

Comment: @GEdgar Do you think it would be worth trying again, including all the CAS's except Mathematica? (Unfortunately I cannot get to original link so I do not see the exact scope of previous proposal). I think Maple proposal had some good responses recently, but didn't make it. I wonder, what was the reason your proposal did not make it :S