# Questions tagged as Maple

Tags: discussion, tagging, area51, se-sites

I have been using MapleSoft's Maple for a while. Previously, I worked with Mathematica and it was great, mostly because there are a lot of resources on the web and [a dedicated stackexchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) for it. So if I had any questions or problems with it, the chance of finding an answer was high. Anyway, recently I was forced to use Maple in a joint project and soon I became frustrated because of the lack of resources compared to Mathematica. I mean, the only place that I could find some useful Q&As with Maple tag was here on mathSE. But it seems so incomplete while most of the questions regarding Maple are more of a *software* question instead of a math question.

So my question is: Are there any chances that the Maple tagged questions be moved or referred to another dedicated site like Mathematica?

BTW, you may not agree with me on the lack of resources on Maple, and you are partly right. But for someone who is used to Mathematica, there are some holes that cannot be filled.

(And I somehow understand the ones arguing that this question is out of scope. Just didn't know where to ask and thought it most likely fits here.)

Comment: a bit off topic ... for questions on Maple, try http://www.mapleprimes.com

Comment: Related: [Proposed SE site for Maple](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25987)

Answer (score 3):

There had been a proposal for an SE site on [Computer Algebra Systems (proposed Stack Exchange area)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/computer-algebra-systems-proposed-stack-exchange-area) .
It was not successful.

You might consider the site on [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com). It has a numerical slant, but its scope even would include more algebraic aspects (at least last time I checked).

But as always, before you ask there, check the Help Center.

Comment: Not to mention I just [started a proposal for Maple](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101911/maple), but it is very likely to fail. Now I am wondering really, how Mathematica could manage to reach this far?! Maybe they had an official support...

Comment: @polfosal Timing is a big thing in this regard. There's another proposal now; hopefully this one will be active enough to enter beta.